# How to access members of GeometryCollection - Python

Tags: python, shapely, geometrycollection

I am using 'intersection' function from Shapely to find junctions of a road network. As i found, intersection returns GeometryCollection. In my case it could be Point, LineString or perhaps MultiLineString. I want to segregate these objects based on their geometry. I only want Point objects for further use. I found similar post [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33066/how-to-split-geometry-collection-into-its-items-using-python-and-qgis-api)

It suggests to use as.GeometryCollection however, in my case it gives:
*p = l1.intersection(l2).asGeometryCollection()

AttributeError: 'GeometryCollection' object has no attribute* 'asGeometryCollection'

here is the sample code: (I expect to get points in junctions[])

```
with open('./lines.geojson') as f:
routes = json.load(f)


junctions =[]
for i in range(len(routes['features'])-1): 
    j =i+1 
    while (j < len(routes['features'])):

        l1 = LineString(routes['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates'])
        l2 = LineString(routes['features'][j]['geometry']['coordinates'])

        p = l1.intersection(l2).asGeometryCollection()
        junctions.append(p[0]) 

        j = j+1
```

Answer (score 3):

If an object A is a GeometryCollection, its content can be accessed using :

```
for geom in A.geoms:
    ...
```

except if A is a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY.

Comment: In shapely 2.0.0: `TypeError: 'GeometryCollection' object is not iterable`

Comment: In Shapely 2+ you must access `A.geoms`

Comment: Damien, you are right, A.geoms is the answer. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've confused the QGIS and Shapely libraries. The code in the similar post doesn't apply to Shapely.

In your case, `p = l1.intersection(l2)` returns an instance of Shapely's `GeometryCollection`. `p[0]` is the first part of that collection. All you need is:

```
p = l1.intersection(l2)
junctions.append(p[0])
```